# cat a file and check it in one line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

My linux command is

```
cat /etc/myfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

My question is how to check if the file /etc/myfile.txt is not empty and save

the file in one command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the conditional expressions in `bash` to check the file exists (`-f` flag) and *not* empty with its `-s` flag.

Also you could just use `cp` to create a new copy of the file instead of `cat`-ing it.

```
if [[ -f /etc/myfile.txt && -s /etc/myfile.txt ]]; then 
    cp /etc/myfile.txt  newfile.txt
fi
```

Not sure why you would bother using a one-line instead of proper readable example. Anyway you can use the above logic as

```
[[ -f /etc/myfile.txt && -s /etc/myfile.txt ]] && cp /etc/myfile.txt newfile.txt
```

Comment: I am not sure why my comments were deleted but I still think `-r` might be useful. Or did you find something that would say otherwise?

Comment: Keeping it a little readable I would write something like `test -f /etc/myfile.txt && test -s /etc/myfile.txt && cp /etc/myfile.txt newfile.txt` when a oneliner is needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
    [ -s "/etc/myfile.txt" ] && cat /etc/myfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

You don't have to `cat` the file,  use `cp` instead.

Here, `-s` option checks if file is non-zero in size. From `man test` on a Linux box,

```
        -s FILE
          FILE exists and has a size greater than zero
```

EDIT: Above solution is enough if `/etc/myfile.txt` is a regular file. If one wants to check if it is a regular file before checking the `non-zero` size, `-f` flag is needed

```
 [[ -f "/etc/myfile.txt" && -s "/etc/myfile.txt" ]] && cp /etc/myfile.txt newfile.txt
```

Comment: This test will also return true on directories with a size greater than 0. For example "/etc" on my machine has a size of 4kb, `[ -s "/etc" ]` returns true while on "/proc" which has a size of 0 on my machine it returns false.